# String.Format("{0:C2}", -1234) (Currency format) treats negative numbers as positive

Tags: c#, vb.net, string-formatting, currency, string.format

I am using `String.Format("{0:C2}", -1234)` to format numbers.

It always formats the amount to a positive number, while I want it to become $ **-** 1234

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I will simply use:

```
FormatCurrency(-1234.56, 2, UseParensForNegativeNumbers:=TriState.False)
```

(in Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings module)

Or in shorter words (this is what im actually going to use):

```
FormatCurrency(-1234.56, 2, 0, 0)
```

Or I will make myself a custom formatcurrency function that uses the VB function passing my custom params.

For further details take a look at the [FormatCurrency Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5(VS.80).aspx) in the msdn.

Answer (score 33):

Am I right in saying it's putting it in brackets, i.e. it's formatting it as `($1,234.00)` ? If so, I believe that's the intended behaviour for the US.

However, you can create your own `NumberFormatInfo` which doesn't behave this way. Take an existing `NumberFormatInfo` which is "mostly right", call `Clone()` to make a mutable copy, and then set the [`CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) appropriately (I think you want value 2).

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var usCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        var clonedNumbers = (NumberFormatInfo) usCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
        clonedNumbers.CurrencyNegativePattern = 2;
        string formatted = string.Format(clonedNumbers, "{0:C2}", -1234);
        Console.WriteLine(formatted);
    }
}
```

This prints $-1,234.00. If you actually want exactly $-1234, you'll need to set the [`CurrencyGroupSizes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupsizes.aspx) property to `new int[]{0}` and use `"{0:C0}"` instead of `"{0:C2}"` as the format string.

EDIT: Here's a helper method you can use which basically does the same thing:

```
private static readonly NumberFormatInfo CurrencyFormat = CreateCurrencyFormat();

private static NumberFormatInfo CreateCurrencyFormat()
{
    var usCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    var clonedNumbers = (NumberFormatInfo) usCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    clonedNumbers.CurrencyNegativePattern = 2;
    return clonedNumbers;
}

public static string FormatCurrency(decimal value)
{
    return value.ToString("C2", CurrencyFormat);
}
```

Comment: Excellent catch. I ran a quick string.Format('{0:C2}', -1234) in boo, got '-$1,234.00' and thought Shimmy was somehow mistaken (sorry Shimmy). I didn't realize that Canada and the US differed on NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern.

Comment: I want to do everything in one line.
Also I wanna get a result format decimal negatives with 2 leading zeros (i.e. $-1234.56)

Comment: If you want to do everything in one call, you'll need to put this in a helper method somewhere. I don't see how you've shown 2 leading zeros in "$-1234.56". You might want to update your question to show what you *actually* want (as you don't want $-1234, contrary to the question).

Comment: BTW, yes, it's putting in brackets, that's weird.

Comment: It's not particularly weird - that's how negative values are represented in various accounting systems.

Comment: Absolutely. (That's why it's part of NumberFormatInfo.)

Comment: How would you do use a custom NumberFormatInfo class in XAML with StringFormat inside a binding expression? I can create a local resource and set the NegativePattern property, but then what?

Comment: In what country's culture negative money values are represented as positive? I want to live there!

Answer (score 25):

Another simple option is manually specify the format string.

```
String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00}", -1234)
```

Or, if the currency symbol needs to be a parameter, you could do this

```
String.Format("{0:" + symbol + "#,##0.00}", -1234)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!
How about "{0:$#,0.00}"? It seems to do the same for me, and I wonder what cases I am missing.

Comment: Microsoft: Simple things made complex.

Comment: Can anybody explain the magic behind this code `String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00}", -1234)`? or where can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#region Format value to currency
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to format input in currency format
    ///  Input:  -12345.55
    ///  Output:$-12,345.55  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Input"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string FormatToCurrency(string Input)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(Input);
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern = 2;
            return string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```