# How can I modify the currency formatter to allow negative money amounts in C#?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

If I have something like:

```
   Decimal moneyAmount = -1522;
```

and then call

```
moneyAmount.toString("c");
```

It will return something like:

($1,522)

Instead, I wish for there to be a negative sign and no paraenthesis.  How can I modify what format provider I send to toString() so I can achieve the following effect:

-$1,522

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.Format("{0:C2}", -1234) (Currency format) treats negative numbers as positive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001114/string-format0c2-1234-currency-format-treats-negative-numbers-as-posit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from: [http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/04/C-sharp.currency](http://web.archive.org/web/20111214015527/http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/04/C-sharp.currency)

```
// set currency format
string curCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo currencyFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(curCulture).NumberFormat;
currencyFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;

number.ToString("c", currencyFormat);
// or string.Format(currencyFormat, "{0:c}", number);
```

Comment: The solution was 99% of the relevant content from the link.  Here's a snapshot of the page: http://web.archive.org/web/20111214015527/http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/04/C-sharp.currency