# How to convert negative values into $ format in C#.NET

Tags: c#

When I use positive `Double` value like `10, 15, 20` and convert to $ using this formula:

```
String Val=Convert.ToDouble("10").ToString("c")
```

Then it returns current value, but if my value is `-10` it returns `($10)`. It automatically appends `()` and add value between this for negative `double` value.

Can anyone tell me how to handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001114/string-format0c2-1234-currency-format-treats-negative-numbers-as-posit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the standard accounting way of sowing a negative money quantity.
You should be able to update this for yourself by changing your Windows settings for currency.

If you want to have a explicitly specific format, you could try

var val = 10.0d;
var str = val.ToString("$#0.##")

or similar.

John Sheehan has a set of cheat-sheets which are handy quick references for this at 
http://john-sheehan.com/blog/

Answer (score 1):

This is a system regional specific setting, in general it's not a good idea to override it in your code because the user has decided to see negatives with () instead of with - in the control panel.

If you really want, you can use the NumberFormatInfo parameter in the overload of ToString but don't do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by modifying this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx

```
System.Treading.Thread.CurrentThread.Culture.NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern = "(${0})";
```